# ngx-image-cropper - how change only the length or width of a cropper

Tags: angular, cropper

In my angular 9 project I use ngx-image-cropper and it is working fine. This is my cropper code:

```html
<image-cropper
  [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"
  [imageURL]="imageUrl"
  [transform]="transform"
  [maintainAspectRatio]="true"
  [aspectRatio]="aspectRatio"
  [canvasRotation]="canvasRotation"
  (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"
></image-cropper>
```

I can use cropper in landscape, portrait and square shapes, also scale, rotate, flip, reset cropped image. But when I change cropper width the height changes depending on the width. How can I change only the length or width of a cropper.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF5ET.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change

```
  [maintainAspectRatio]="false"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped.